# Preventing input errors

Tags: java, exception, input, try-catch

I made this java code to input a number:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int temp;

    do{

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(in);
        out.print("enter number ");
        temp = scan.nextInt();




        if(temp >= 5 && temp <= 40){ 
            int x = (temp-1)*2 +1; 
            int y = x/2;  
            int z = 1;  
            for(int i=0; i<temp-1; i++) 
            {
                for(int j=0; j<=y; j++) 
                {
                    out.print(" ");
                }
                for(int k = 0; k<z; k++) 
                {
                    out.print("|");
                }
                out.println(); 
                y--;
                z+=2; 
            }

            for(int c = 0; c < 1 + temp/10; c++) {
                for (int i = 0; i <= x / 2; i++)
                {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.println("|");
            }
        }else{
            out.print("enter a number between 5 and 40");
        }
    }while(temp != 0);
}
```

}

However, this will return an error if I enter for example a letter or an invalid character. I would like to know how to, instead of making the program crash, make it display an error message and then asking again the question until the entry is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;

public class Main

{

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    int temp=0;
    boolean error=false;
    do{
        error=false;
        try
        {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("enter number ");
            temp = scan.nextInt();
            if(temp==0)
                break;



            if(temp >= 5 && temp <= 40)
            { 
                int x = (temp-1)*2 +1; 
                int y = x/2;  
                int z = 1;  
                for(int i=0; i<temp-1; i++) 
                {
                    for(int j=0; j<=y; j++) 
                    {
                        System.out.print(" ");
                    }
                    for(int k = 0; k<z; k++) 
                    {
                        System.out.print("|");
                    }
                    System.out.println(); 
                    y--;
                    z+=2; 
                }

                for(int c = 0; c < 1 + temp/10; c++) 
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= x / 2; i++)
                    {
                        System.out.print(" ");
                    }
                    System.out.println("|");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("enter a number between 5 and 40");
            }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a valid number..try again");
            error=true;
        }
    }while(temp != 0 || error);
}
```

}

When the error or exception occurs i.e. in scan.nextInt() an Exception is thrown and as you have not caught the exception the JVM stops executing the program.

So always write statements which can throw Exceptions within a try{ } block and immediately follow it with a catch(Exception e) {} block to catch the exception. If no exception occurs then catch block will not execute. If any error occurs inside try{} block : control jumps to catch block and it is executed and all other statements in try{} (after the erroneous line) are ignored.

try
{
    ..
    error
    .. // skipped
    ..
}
catch(Exception e)
{
   ...
   ...// handle exception
}
// control comes here after executing catch block

Comment: your answer needs some explantion

Comment: it is not good practice to throw exception in main method as far as I know

Comment: @KickButtowski.. he isn't throwing the exception. he is catching it

Comment: can your read this part?   public static void main(String args[])throws IOException

Comment: @KickButtowski.. sorry didn't see that

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however this doesnt seem to works since I have a if statement in a while loop(see full code above).My temp variable say to be duplicated when I try your code

Comment: @KickButtowski : its mandatory for a method to either catch or declare its throwing an exception if that exception might occur inside it..... and i am used to taking input with BufferedReader...so if you have something like 

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

Then you must declare to throw it or catch it. in my case i didn't catch it

Comment: @ShouvikRoy I still disagree with throwing exception in main method :)

Comment: @KickButtowski : well I'm always take criticism positively, thanks for enriching my curiousity as to why it is :)

Comment: @ShouvikRoy Thanks for your help! This code works right as it should! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Read in the value from the user as a string and then try to parse it to a number in a try {} catch{} block, if an exception is thrown parsing it, tell the user only numbers are acceptable. if not continue processing with the number they gave you.

Comment: I am more visual; could you show me an example or use my code? thanks

Comment: @Johnny_b: Google is your friend. There are thousands of examples. Just look for try/catch string, or something similar.

Comment: I like your answer the most if you can format it better with a sample code I will +1

Answer (score 0):

Extending from @Shouvik Roy's answer..

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bingo {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        boolean isInt = false;
        int temp;
        System.out.print("enter a number ");
        do{
             Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

             try
             {
                 temp = scan.nextInt();
                 isInt = true;
             }
             catch(Exception e)
             {
                System.out.println("Couldn't read number. Reason - "+e.getMessage()); 
                System.out.println("Enter a valid number ");
             }

        }while(!isInt);

    }
}
```

------------------Edit-------------------

```
boolean isInt = false;
System.out.print("enter a number ");


do{
    try
     {
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(in);
         temp = scan.nextInt();
         isInt = true;
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
        System.out.println("Couldn't read number. Reason - "+e.getMessage()); 
        System.out.println("Enter a valid number ");
     }
}while(!isInt)
```

Comment: if your scanner bump into a issue how you gonna handle it? do you thinking giving an answer without explanation is right and helpful ?

Comment: Thanks, but could you put it into my code to see what you exactly mean? I have some if and while statement so I dont know if your method is 100% compatible with my code

Comment: it says isInt cannot be resolaved to a variable

Comment: did you include the top 2 lines? boolean isInt = false;

Answer (score 0):

The [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) has a method to check if the next token is an integer: [hasNextInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt()).

You could do this:

```
package com.sandbox;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter an integer:");
        while (!scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            System.err.println("Wrong! Enter an integer");
            scanner.next();
        }
        System.out.println("Your integer was: " + scanner.nextInt());
    }


}
```

This worked as you'd want on a windows console.  I'm a little concerned it'll work incorrectly on Linux/Mac.  Anyone mind testing it out for me?  If this works, I like it best because there's no try/catch.

Comment: just a question if your scanner bump into  issue how you gonna handle it?

Comment: @KickButtowski what issue would it run into?

Comment: @KickButtowski apparently I'm not.  I tried this out without running into an issue.

Comment: @KickButtowski you should tell me what input you think will cause this to fail.

Comment: it seems you are smart enough I always thought we have to use try catch block for scanner too :)

Comment: @KickButtowski me too.  One "problem" I found was that if you type in "1 asdf" it will accept the "1".  That's not necessarily an issue, depends on the requirements.  It won't error.

Comment: cool I'll take a look at it.thank you for being patient and mature :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I pasted my full code above,could you put it directly in my code? im not sure its 100% compatible with your method since it has while and if statement... thanks!

Comment: @Johnny_b sorry, but I'm not going to go that far.  As a hint, you should assign my `scanner.nextInt()` to your `temp`